# Adding User Authentication to MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I was assigned my first ever MVC 5 projet, it is a simple Lending System with lots of CRUD operations which is almost done except that I have not implemented user authentication to the app yet.

**My project has 4 layers**: 
1. App.Web - mvc web app 
2. App.DataAccess - crud repositories
3. App.Common- my edmx/entities and interfaces
 
4. App.Business - services / logical operations

Now I just need to add user authentication to complete my project. Just a simple individual user account but I need to implement user roles. I do NOT need any other api login feature (facebook, google etc). But I am too lazy to code this and wanted to use asp.net identity instead. So when I created my MVC 5 App.Web, I checked individual user authentication so everything I need is now referenced in my App.Web but I dont know how to make it work with my application layer.

Is there a way I can use asp.net identity in my web application? How can I do this to fit in my application architecture nicely? Please help!

Comment: possible [unnecessary use of tags in the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: As for the issue of lazy, see [personal productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/too-lazy-to-do-programming)

Comment: You need to move the bits you need in the application layer into the application layer. e.g. `ApplicationUser` will go into `App.Common`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to understand the structure and customization of ASP.NET Identity you can create empty project on visual studio and download [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples) package from NuGet.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project is not too big I mean if have just some simple User roles and Login/Log out system ,so I recommend you to use ASP.NET membership system.it is very easy to manage user's and roles.Please take a look into the following article:

[Introduction to Membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=VS.100).aspx)